# Table and div positioning isn't lining up

Tags: html, css

So, here is my problem; I am trying to position a `div` that is right next to a `table`. I want them to line up side by side. Like it is, they line up with the text above all of the rest of it. Check out my vision board below:

[image: Text]
[image: Rest]

Except I actually want the words "Signature Editor" to be at the top (photo problem) rather than the bottom. So that is what I want. It all to be lined up side by side. However, here is what is actually is:
[image: Full signature]

As you can see, the "Signature Editor" text is above the table rather than lined up like how I want it to be (see my vision board).

Here is my code:

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#signatureEditorText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 15px;
}
hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}
#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  }
#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.otherText {
  color: seaGreen;
}
#emailAddress {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#extra1, #extra2, #extra3, #extra4, #extra5, #extra6 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id = "signatureEditorText"><h2>Signature Editor</h2></div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image" title = "Picture to be displayed">
        </td>
        <td  class = "spacer"></td>
        <td rowspan = "4">
            <hr>
        </td>
        <td  class = "spacer"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "fullName">Billy Staples</div></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "job"><i>Programmer</i></div></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "jobLocationText">at <b id = "jobLocation">My Company</b></div></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id = "contactInfo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "emailAddress"><span class = "otherText">Email: </span><span id = "emailAddressText">email@domain.com</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "phoneNumber"><span class = "otherText">Phone: </span><span id = "phoneNumberFirst">111</span>-<span id = "phoneNumberSecond">222</span>-<span id = "phoneNumberThird">3333</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "officePhoneNumber"><span class = "otherText">Office Phone: </span><span id = "officePhoneNumberFirst">444</span>-<span id = "officePhoneNumberSecond">555</span>-<span id = "officePhoneNumberThird">6666</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "address"><span class = "otherText">Address: </span><span id = "addressText">1379 Philadelphia Avenue</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "website"><span class = "otherText">Website: </span><span id = "websiteText">example.com</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra1"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra1Label"></span><span id = "extra1Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra2"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra2Label"></span><span id = "extra2Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra3"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra3Label"></span><span id = "extra3Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra4"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra4Label"></span><span id = "extra4Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra5"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra5Label"></span><span id = "extra5Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra6"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra6Label"></span><span id = "extra6Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And a JSFiddle of it is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CyanCoding/he84kv8n/20/).

Also, here are some methods I have tried: `display: inline;`, `display: inline-block;`, `display: block;`.

Thanks!

Comment: u impose e-mail? why do u use a `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want your text to be displayed to the left of your table, and at the top, so that it lines up with the avatar? That can be achieved by simply setting `float: left` on the `#signatureEditorText`:

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
#signatureEditorText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}
#image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 15px;
}
hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}
#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  }
#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.otherText {
  color: seaGreen;
}
#emailAddress {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#extra1, #extra2, #extra3, #extra4, #extra5, #extra6 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id = "signatureEditorText"><h2>Signature Editor</h2></div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image" title = "Picture to be displayed">
        </td>
        <td  class = "spacer"></td>
        <td rowspan = "4">
            <hr>
        </td>
        <td  class = "spacer"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "fullName">Billy Staples</div></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "job"><i>Programmer</i></div></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><div id = "jobLocationText">at <b id = "jobLocation">My Company</b></div></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id = "contactInfo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "emailAddress"><span class = "otherText">Email: </span><span id = "emailAddressText">email@domain.com</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "phoneNumber"><span class = "otherText">Phone: </span><span id = "phoneNumberFirst">111</span>-<span id = "phoneNumberSecond">222</span>-<span id = "phoneNumberThird">3333</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "officePhoneNumber"><span class = "otherText">Office Phone: </span><span id = "officePhoneNumberFirst">444</span>-<span id = "officePhoneNumberSecond">555</span>-<span id = "officePhoneNumberThird">6666</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "address"><span class = "otherText">Address: </span><span id = "addressText">1379 Philadelphia Avenue</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "website"><span class = "otherText">Website: </span><span id = "websiteText">example.com</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra1"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra1Label"></span><span id = "extra1Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra2"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra2Label"></span><span id = "extra2Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra3"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra3Label"></span><span id = "extra3Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra4"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra4Label"></span><span id = "extra4Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra5"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra5Label"></span><span id = "extra5Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id = "extra6"><span class = "otherText" id = "extra6Label"></span><span id = "extra6Text"> </span></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make the parent `display: flex;` to put the 2 elements in a row, aligned to `flex-start` by default, then add `margin: 0` to the `h2`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
}

#signatureEditorText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

#image {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.spacer {
  width: 15px;
}

hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}

#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.otherText {
  color: seaGreen;
}

#emailAddress {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#extra1,
#extra2,
#extra3,
#extra4,
#extra5,
#extra6 {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="signatureEditorText">
  <h2>Signature Editor</h2></div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image" title="Picture to be displayed">
    </td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
    <td rowspan="4">
      <hr>
    </td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="jobLocationText">at <b id="jobLocation">My Company</b></div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="contactInfo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="emailAddress"><span class="otherText">Email: </span><span id="emailAddressText">email@domain.com</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="phoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Phone: </span><span id="phoneNumberFirst">111</span>-<span id="phoneNumberSecond">222</span>-<span id="phoneNumberThird">3333</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="officePhoneNumber"><span class="otherText">Office Phone: </span><span id="officePhoneNumberFirst">444</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberSecond">555</span>-<span id="officePhoneNumberThird">6666</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="address"><span class="otherText">Address: </span><span id="addressText">1379 Philadelphia Avenue</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="website"><span class="otherText">Website: </span><span id="websiteText">example.com</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra1"><span class="otherText" id="extra1Label"></span><span id="extra1Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra2"><span class="otherText" id="extra2Label"></span><span id="extra2Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra3"><span class="otherText" id="extra3Label"></span><span id="extra3Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra4"><span class="otherText" id="extra4Label"></span><span id="extra4Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra5"><span class="otherText" id="extra5Label"></span><span id="extra5Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="extra6"><span class="otherText" id="extra6Label"></span><span id="extra6Text"> </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was trying to get the text "Signature Editor" on the top and not the bottom.

Comment: @CyanCoding oh sorry, I was going off the picture, missed the part where you said you wanted the text at the top. Updated - better?